# Get data from xml url using Python

Tags: python, xml

I want to use URL (https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/sitemap.xml) to get list of recipes url's in Python. I try to use xmltodict, but as I can see, it does not convert the text in a good way. My code:

```
import urllib.request
import xmltodict

with urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/sitemap.xml') as url:
    data = url.read()

data = xmltodict.parse(data)
print(data)
```

And part of the result:

> [...] OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yoghurtspicedchicken_74830'),
> ('lastmod', '2012-06-07'), ('image:image', OrderedDict([('image:loc',
> 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/yoghurtspicedchicken_74830_16x9.jpg')]))]),
> OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yoghurt_and_muesli_61842'),
> ('lastmod', '2018-04-18')]), OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yoghurt_cake_87253'), ('lastmod',
> '2020-03-31'), ('image:image', OrderedDict([('image:loc',
> 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/yoghurt_cake_87253_16x9.jpg')]))]),
> OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshirecurdpie_86473'),
> ('lastmod', '2019-05-23')]), OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshireparkin_83745'),
> ('lastmod', '2019-01-02')]), OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshirepotwithchri_87677'),
> ('lastmod', '2018-12-03')]), OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshirepuddingswit_92145'),
> ('lastmod', '2016-09-13')]), OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshirepuddings_86010'),
> ('lastmod', '2018-08-08'), ('image:image', OrderedDict([('image:loc',
> 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/yorkshirepuddings_86010_16x9.jpg')]))]),
> OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshirepuddingviap_9974'),
> ('lastmod', '2015-12-07')]), OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshirepuddingwith_83703'),
> ('lastmod', '2018-10-30')]), OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshirepudding_81824'),
> ('lastmod', '2019-01-21'), ('image:image', OrderedDict([('image:loc',
> 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/yorkshirepudding_81824_16x9.jpg')]))]),
> OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshirepudding_93848'),
> ('lastmod', '2018-08-08'), ('image:image', OrderedDict([('image:loc',
> 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/yorkshirepudding_93848_16x9.jpg')]))]),
> OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshire_curd_tart_20002'),
> ('lastmod', '2019-01-03'), ('image:image', OrderedDict([('image:loc',
> 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/yorkshire_curd_tart_20002_16x9.jpg')]))]),
> OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshire_curd_tart_23874'),
> ('lastmod', '2019-01-03')]), OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshire_curd_tart_63644'),
> ('lastmod', '2016-09-19')]), OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshire_oatmeal_parkin_13911'),
> ('lastmod', '2016-09-19')]), OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshire_puddings_61798'),
> ('lastmod', '2018-11-28'), ('image:image', OrderedDict([('image:loc',
> 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/yorkshire_puddings_61798_16x9.jpg')]))]),
> OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshire_puddings_and_40867'),
> ('lastmod', '2018-12-04')]), OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshire_puddings_with_15870'),
> ('lastmod', '2018-04-30')]), OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshire_puddings_with_50889'),
> ('lastmod', '2019-02-11')]), OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshire_pudding_69240'),
> ('lastmod', '2019-12-10'), ('image:image', OrderedDict([('image:loc',
> 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/yorkshire_pudding_69240_16x9.jpg')]))]),
> OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshire_pudding_wraps_73052'),
> ('lastmod', '2019-09-30'), ('image:image', OrderedDict([('image:loc',
> 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/yorkshire_pudding_wraps_73052_16x9.jpg')]))]),
> OrderedDict([('loc',
> 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/yorkshire_tapas_puddings_93245'),
> ('lastmod', '2016-09-14'), ('image:image', OrderedDict([('image:loc',
> 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/yorkshire_tapas_puddings_93245_16x9.jpg')]))]),
> [...]

I want to get only URLs, that are included in  tag in XML and filter them according to the pattern "https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/"

Comment: in this case, it could be easy to extract the URLs using regex.

Comment: How much of the document do you want, just the url/loc urls?

Comment: Yes, I want to make list of urls that are in url/loc and additionally fits in the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the convenience method, `xmltodict`, that works on simpler, flatter XML documents, consider parsing the XML and map to dictionary with Python's built-in `xml.etree` module.

Be sure to assign namespaces and conditionally retrieve image since it is not always present under `<url>` nodes.

```
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

with urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/sitemap.xml') as url:
    data = url.read()

xml = et.fromstring(data)
nsmp = {"doc": "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9",
        "image" : "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"}
       
recipies_dict = [] 

for url in xml.findall('doc:url', namespaces = nsmp):
   loc = url.find('doc:loc', namespaces = nsmp).text
  
   img_node = url.find('image:image', namespaces = nsmp)   
   img = img_node.find('image:loc', namespaces = nsmp).text if img_node is not None else None

   recipies_dict.append({'loc':loc, 'img': img})
```

**Output**

```
len(recipes_dict)
# 20084

recipes_dict[1:20]    
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/', 'img': None}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes', 'img': None}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/chefs', 'img': None}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/programmes', 'img': None}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/ingredients', 'img': None}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/seasons', 'img': None}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/occasions', 'img': None}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/cuisines', 'img': None}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/techniques', 'img': None}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/10minutepizza_87314', 'img': None}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/15_minute_pasta_33407', 'img': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/15_minute_pasta_33407_16x9.jpg'}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/1_creamy_chicken_pasta_24218', 'img': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/1_creamy_chicken_pasta_24218_16x9.jpg'}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/1_hoisin_spinach_and_egg_86057', 'img': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/1_hoisin_spinach_and_egg_86057_16x9.jpg'}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/1_mixed_vegetable_and_84703', 'img': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/1_mixed_vegetable_and_84703_16x9.jpg'}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/2_hour_christmas_dinner_79341', 'img': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/2_hour_christmas_dinner_79341_16x9.jpg'}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/3d_biscuits_29555', 'img': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/3d_biscuits_29555_16x9.jpg'}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/3wayswithlemoncurd_67266', 'img': None}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/3_stir-fry_sauces_52376', 'img': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/3_stir-fry_sauces_52376_16x9.jpg'}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/5-ingredient_33925', 'img': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/5-ingredient_33925_16x9.jpg'}
# {'loc': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/5-minute_chicken_noodle_78996', 'img': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/food/ic/food_16x9_320/recipes/5-minute_chicken_noodle_78996_16x9.jpg'}
```